# Can I format the syntax of a variable encoded via PHP's json_encode() in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, php, json

EDIT: Posted my own answer which solved it. Sorry for the time of others I wasted on this silly thing.

Originally I was using a URL to get a JSON file, then using file_get_contents(url) into a php variable to get the JSON string passed to it. I'm assuming this initializes the variable as a special JSON type due to my issues.

If I try to create the variable "dynamically" (hardcoded for question purposes) and use json_encode($json) into $data3, it does **not** format in a way that my JS FullCalendar Event can read it. I tried cheating with $data2 by just passing a straight string that is exactly the same as $data when echoed. Doesn't work for my JSON feed to calendar.

So somehow I need to get $data3 to the right syntax, while retaining JSON property.

How can I manipulate the syntax of the json_encode output?

page-template.php

```
$url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/calendar.json';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data2 = '{ "className" : "mooncenter", "title" : "big energy", "start" : "2019-04-23" }';

$json= '{ "className" : "mooncenter", "title" : "big energy", "start" : "2019-04-23" }';

$data3 = json_encode($json);


echo $data;
echo $data2;
echo $data3;
```

Echo Output.

```
//$data outputs

{ "className" : "mooncenter", "title" : "big energy", "start" : "2019-04-23" }

//$data2 outputs the same, but does not work because not json encode?

{ "className" : "mooncenter", "title" : "big energy", "start" : "2019-04-23" }

//$data3 outputs weirdly, with double quotes or slashes depending on
// if I encapsuled the PHP init with '' or "". Below is one example.

"{ \"className\" : \"mooncenter\", \"title\" : \"big energy\", \"start\" : \"2019-04-23\" }"
```

I need $data3 to look like the first two ones, while retaining the json encode properties.

Is this possible? That would solve my dynamic JSON creation issues without passing a URL and also give me eternal peace.

Comment: That's funny. `json_encode()` is used to encode a PHP Object or Associative Array into a JSON String. `json_decode()` turns a JSON encoded String to a PHP Object, or Associative Array with second parameter `true`.

Comment: This question seems about a clumsy workaround for a problem that lies elsewhere.

Comment: It is, I don't know how to dynamically create JSON file, only how to pass a hardcoded one. There are many layers involved (per client, temporary file, running SQL query outside of my main PHP) that I need to take into account. If I can just run a SQL query and dynamically create my variable as i'm showing above, then all my problems would be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the call of variable was literally

```
//  <?php echo $data2; ?>
```

This above crashes it, yet this below:

```
//  <?php echo $data; ?>
```

Does not crash. I thought because it was in memory, but I reopened incognito mode and it still works. I assumed the comment line // did nothing because the text did not go green in VSCode and the original $data worked.

I should have just removed the comment lines from the get go but something something 12h workday brain fart moment. Why it works half and half I honestly don't have the energy to care. Problem is solved.

Comment: Don't know what VSCode is doing for you there, but placing the `//` like you have will put them in the HTML, and still execute the PHP code. They are not special characters to HTML, so it will just leave them there unchanged. To comment out your echos, you want `<?php // echo $data2; ?>`; this way, they're in the PHP, which will recognize them.

Comment: Yeah, I was just commenting out for a sec and forgot to remove them. The puzzling thing is that it works with one variable and not the other, but removing the // fixed my issues. At this point i'm not gonna try to  decipher it because, well, they shouldn't have been there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming this initializes the variable as a special JSON type due to my issues.

You are incorrect. `json_encode()` converts a PHP object -- usually an array -- into a JSON string. There is no JSON type in PHP.

Your text file already contains JSON text, so loading the contents of that file into a variable using `file_get_contents()` already gives you a JSON string. You do not need to encode it a second time. Whatever is going wrong is somewhere outside this code.

Comment: You misread my code. $data1 comes from a JSON file, $data2 is a hardcoded string. $data3 is a string encoded from $json. There is no double encoding going on here

Comment: `$data1` and `$data2` are both strings. They appear to be identical. There is nothing special about the first one just because it was read from a file whose name ended with ".json".

Comment: That's why i'm confused. They are both exactly the same string, I am interchangeably switching them for one another inside the same JS Script. One causes my calendar to trash, the other works. This makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try to add change your code like following

```
    $myObj->name = "John";
    $myObj->age = 30;
    $myObj->city = "New York";

    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

    echo $myJSON;
```

output

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

This will definitely help you, in this way you don't need to put key value pair manually as strings :) cheers

Comment: The output looks good, it's the same minus the spaces, however my JS script is still crashing when using that variable. I just don't understand why. They output the same thing...but $data works fine

Comment: Yeah it is, it was a typo error you can see on my own answer. It's nonsensical that it "sorta" worked but yeah, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data3['name'] = "John";
$data3['age'] = 30;
$data3['city'] = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;

//decode
$phpArray = json_decode($myJSON, true);
print_r($phpArray);
```

Comment: While the output is the same as the original $data, this is still crashing my calendar. I don't understand why. They both output the exact same string...but interchangeably act differently.